# Stop PowerPoint 2013 from animating pictures when going back?

Tags: animation, navigation, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I created a master slide for full-screen pictures. There are no slide transitions and no animations.

When I get to such a full-screen slide however, PowerPoint will do a fade-in on that picture (automatically). I'm okay with that.

If I go back to such a slide however, it will not fade in the picture until I hit the left arrow key another time. This means if I'm on slide 4, and all 3 previous slides use the full-screen picture layout, then I have to hit the arrow key 6(!) times.

Is there a way to make it go back and have the content revealed, or at least start the in-animation of the picture automatically?